# AngularJS: Error: event is undefined (Firefox only)

Tags: angularjs, events

Even though I'm defining the event and it works in Chrome it does not work in Firefox?

```
app.controller('lightbox_close_controller', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {

        $scope.close_rating_lightbox = function(event) {

            if (!$(".lightbox").hasClass("mobile_ratebox")) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                $("#image_in_lightbox_inside").empty();
            }
        }
    }

]);
```

Comment: It should be $event over here and pass the same in your html as well

Comment: show the related html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pass `$event` from ui

like

```
<button ng-click="close_rating_lightbox($event)">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just one more question regarding this. Even though I pass $event, in the function I can call event. Why is it working without the $ sign?

Comment: event property is override by angular $event so your code not works

Comment: Same behaviour like window to be $window, setTimeout be $timeout

Comment: function pass only value or reference if function has parameter then value or refrence will pass into that parameter according to position of passed data

Comment: Thanks. Had been hitting my head on the wall for past one hour.

Comment: @Yasser you are welcome :) glad to know that my answer helped you

Comment: HEY aNIK tHANKS :) , it was tricky one :) and you hv given nice resolutions works for me too

Comment: Hi @AnikIslamAbhi, can you please answer this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38600629/how-do-i-use-event-in-angularjs-with-firefox-as-its-saying-that-event-is-undefi

Answer (score 2):

the same issue in Angular 2  , firefox is more strict in event declaration

```
//in chrom works fine  
//in firefox throws event is undefined
     @HostListener('click') onClick() {
         console.info(event);
    }



// to fix it you have to add
     @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(event) {
     console.log(event)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that you can also get this error if you forget to add the event argument if in the event handler, i.e.

```
onClicked(event){
}
```