# How do I use event in Angularjs with firefox as it's saying that event is undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's my Angular function which basically updates data when you double-click on the required field, change it's value and press enter:

```
 $scope.contentEdit = function(data, event) {
    console.log("event", event); //this function triggers when the user edit student's data from the table and updates new data to local storage.
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.students.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.students[i].studentName == data) {
            $scope.students[i].studentName = event.target.innerText;
        } else if ($scope.students[i].Marks == data) {
            $scope.students[i].Marks = parseInt(event.target.innerText);
            $scope.students[i].pass = ($scope.students[i].Marks > 65) ? true : false;
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem('studentsList', JSON.stringify($scope.students));
    event.target.contentEditable = event.target.contentEditable == "false" ? "true" : "false";
};
```

I have passed $event from my html as contentEdit(student.studentName, $event) but it still doesn't work.
Whenever I double click on the field then it's logging the double click event successfully on console but as soon as I hit Enter key, It's throwing and error that event is undefined.

Comment: Could you post your **HTML**?

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Hi Anik, thank you for responding, I got it fixed, actually this function was called by another function and I forgot to pass the event from that function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a `ng-dblclick` directive? If yes, I suppose you has a syntax error.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.contentEdit = function(data, event) {
        console.log(event);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-dblclick="contentEdit(1, $event)">dblclick me to see the console</div>
</div>
```